# task.getResult().getDownloadUrl().toString() method not working

Tags: android

task.getResult().getDownloadUrl().toString() method not working ,in android studio I am a new learner in the field of Android can I find someone to help me solve the problem ??? this is my full code of setupActivity class.

---

task.getResult().getDownloadUrl().toString() method not working ,in android studio I am a new learner in the field of Android can I find someone to help me solve the problem ??? this is my full code of setupActivity class.

```
package com.example.ihsan;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImage;
import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Objects;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class SetupActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText UserName, FullName, CountryName;
    private Button SaveInformationbuttion;
    private CircleImageView ProfileImage;
    private ProgressDialog loadingBar;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private DatabaseReference UsersRef;
    private StorageReference UserProfileImageRef;

    String currentUserID;
    final static int Gallery_Pick = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_setup);


        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        UsersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(currentUserID);
        UserProfileImageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("Profile Images");


        UserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.setup_username);
        FullName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.setup_full_name);
        CountryName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.setup_country_name);
        SaveInformationbuttion = (Button) findViewById(R.id.setup_information_button);
        ProfileImage = (CircleImageView) findViewById(R.id.setup_profile_image);
        loadingBar = new ProgressDialog(this);


        SaveInformationbuttion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                SaveAccountSetupInformation();
            }
        });



        ProfileImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
                galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, Gallery_Pick);
            }
        });



        ProfileImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
                galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, Gallery_Pick);
            }
        });

        UsersRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("profileimage")) {
                        String image = dataSnapshot.child("profileimage").getValue().toString();
                        Picasso.with(SetupActivity.this).load(image).placeholder(R.drawable.profile).into(ProfileImage);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this, "Please select profile image first...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                }


            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode==Gallery_Pick && resultCode==RESULT_OK && data!=null)
        {
            Uri ImageUri = data.getData();

            CropImage.activity()
                    .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                    .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
                    .start(this);
        }

        if(requestCode==CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE)
        {
            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);

            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
                loadingBar.setTitle("Profile Image");
                loadingBar.setMessage("Please wait, while we updating your profile image...");
                loadingBar.show();
                loadingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

                Uri resultUri = result.getUri();

                StorageReference filePath = UserProfileImageRef.child(currentUserID + ".jpg");

                filePath.putFile(resultUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull final Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task)
                    {
                        if(task.isSuccessful())
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this, "Profile Image stored successfully...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            final String downloadUrl = task.getResult().getDownloadUrl().toString();







                            UsersRef.child("profileimage").setValue(downloadUrl)
                                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task)
                                        {
                                            if(task.isSuccessful())
                                            {
                                                Intent selfIntent = new Intent(SetupActivity.this, SetupActivity.class);
                                                startActivity(selfIntent);

                                                Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this, "Profile Image stored to  Successfully...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                loadingBar.dismiss();
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                String message = task.getException().getMessage();
                                                Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this, "Error Occurred: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                loadingBar.dismiss();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error Occurred: Image can not be cropped. Try Again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                loadingBar.dismiss();
            }
        }
    }

    private void SaveAccountSetupInformation() {

        String username = UserName.getText().toString();
        String fullname = FullName.getText().toString();
        String country = CountryName.getText().toString();


        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(username)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please write your username...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(fullname)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please write your full name...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(country)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please write your country...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            loadingBar.setTitle("Saving Information");
            loadingBar.setMessage("Please wait, while we are creating your new Account...");
            loadingBar.show();
            loadingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

            HashMap userMap = new HashMap();
            userMap.put("username", username);
            userMap.put("fullname", fullname);
            userMap.put("country", country);
            userMap.put("status", "Hey there, I'm using IHSAN , developed by Mohamed EL Ghazali.");
            userMap.put("gender", "none");
            userMap.put("dob", "none");
            userMap.put("relationshipstatus", "none");
            UsersRef.updateChildren(userMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task)
                {
                    if(task.isSuccessful())
                    {
                        SendUserToMainActivity();
                        Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this, "your Account is created Successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        loadingBar.dismiss();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        String message =  task.getException().getMessage();
                        Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this, "Error Occurred: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        loadingBar.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    }

    private void SendUserToMainActivity() {

        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SetupActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(mainIntent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To solve the problem about "*The method getDownloadUrl()...*"

use these firebase versions:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.2'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:2.1.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this Document; Set Complete Listener for getDownloadUrl() https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files?authuser=0#download_data_via_url

```
    //it is better not to use space in child name
        StorageReference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference()
.child("ProfileImages")
.child(currentUserID + ".jpg")

     storageRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
            // Got the download URL for 'path/to/aFile'
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            // Handle any errors
        }
    });
```

Comment: pleas can you change it in my code for me plz  ? my experience is incomplete in dealing with codes

Comment: what is your path to file or storage references?

Comment: it s not a storage reference!

Comment: can you tell me how can I get my storage references ??

Comment: check the answer now

Comment: what I have to Write her in "// Got the download URL for 'path/to/aFile'" ???
 and here "        // Handle any errors" ??

Comment: just post your complete class code then i ll help you

Comment: check out the answer

Answer (score 0):

Please note that `task.getResult().getDownloadUrl()` 
is now deprecated, you can replace below part in your code

```
filePath.putFile(resultUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull final Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task)
    {
        if(task.isSuccessful())
        {
            Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this, "Profile Image stored successfully...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            final String downloadUrl = task.getResult().getDownloadUrl().toString();
```

with

```
filePath.putFile(resultUri)
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                final Task<Uri> firebaseUri = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
                firebaseUri.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                        final String downloadUrl = uri.toString();
                        // complete the rest of your code
                    }
                });

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make change here:

```
 filePath.putFile(resultUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull final Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task)
                {
                    if(task.isSuccessful())
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this, "Profile Image stored successfully...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        final String downloadUrl = task.getResult().getDownloadUrl().toString();
```

Replace above code with this:

```
filePath.putFile(resultUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    filePath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

                            final String downloadUrl = uri.getDownloadUrl().toString();

                            });
                        }
                    });
```